# How to get the users desktop/laptop ip address in Oracle SQL procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, ip-address, hostname

I am using server's putty session to connect to oracle SQL plus and did below queries to get host name and ip address.

these queries are returing the host name and IP address of the application server but my requirement is to get the users laptop host name and IP address to know the user host name and IP address instead of server host name and ip address.

Can anyone help to get the user (laptop) host name and IP address instead of server host name and ip address?

```
select SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'HOST', 15) INTO v_host from dual;
select SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'IP_ADDRESS', 15) INTO v_ipaddress from dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','IP_ADDRESS') FROM dual

You can use the above query to get the IP address of the client.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible as the `Oracle Sql*plus` has no information about your `putty` client.

So for the `Oracle Db` the client is your Application Server - form where `Sql*plus` calls are originating.

One thing you could probably do is set `client_info` and use that extra information to determine the real client.

Something like this (inside sql script)

`DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.set_client_info(client_info => '&1');`

In that case you should pass `putty's` client value (`$SSH_CLIENT` environment variable) into your sql script:

```
sqlplus -S user/password@host << EOF
@/opt/D2RQ/file.sql $SSH_CLIENT
exit;
EOF
```